# percent sign inside function

Tags: javascript, html

The widths of my DIV tags are metered in percents, but I have a syntax error using the percent in the way I pasted in the code. Please help me and show me how to fix it.

```
           '<div style="float: left;">' + this.PdriverName + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '</div>' +

            '<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width:' + parseInt(this.OrderCount) + '* 50 %>px">' +


             '<div style="border: 0px; float: left; width:' + ((parseFloat(this.OrderCount) - parseFloat(this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull)) / parseFloat(this.OrderCount)) * 100 + '%;">' + this.OrderCount + '</div>' +

              '<div style="border: 0px; float: right; width:' + (parseFloat(this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull) / parseFloat(this.OrderCount)) * 100 + '%; background-color: red;">' + this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull + '</div>'
```

Comment: What is this code? Is it JavaScript or what? Why did you tag your question as `asp.net`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
        '<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width:' +
         parseInt(this.OrderCount) + '* 50 %>px">' +
```

To this if you want percents (which doesn't seem to make much sense with the 50):

```
        '<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width:' +
         (parseInt(this.OrderCount) * 50) + '%;">' +
```

or:

```
        '<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width:' +
         (parseInt(this.OrderCount) * 50) + 'px;">' +
```

If what you meant to do was use pixels for sizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<div style="border: 3px solid black; float: left; width:' + 
     parseInt(this.OrderCount)*.5 + 'px;">' +
```